# how to handle store procedure return one to many Relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

i have a store procedure get table Category and Produce 
this is my entity

```
public class Category
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my store procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCategoryAndProductByCategoryId
    @Id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * from Category as c
    inner join Product on c.Id = p.CategoryId
    where c.Id = @Id
END
GO


public virtual ObjectResult<Category_Result> GetCategoryAndProductByCategoryId(Nullable<int> Id)
        {
            var IdParameter = Id.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("Id", Id) :
                new ObjectParameter("Id", typeof(System.Int32));


            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Category_Result>("GetCategoryAndProductByCategoryId", IdParameter);
        }
```

how can i map to one Category and list Product Because store Product always return list object, i mean Category is list Object. how can i Bind it to Category

Comment: You need `CategoryId` property in `Product` entity. Also please clarify *i mean Category is list Object. how can i Bind it to Category*

Comment: when i execute that select statement store will return to me list object of category and product, so how can i bind that list to one object category and list object product

Comment: Are you using ORM?

Comment: i am using entity framwork

Comment: you could use `navigation properties`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: but actually 2 table have no relationship, so does it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing your stored procedure like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCategoryAndProductByCategoryId]
    @Id INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
                C.[Id],
                C.[Name]
        FROM
                [dbo].[Category] C
        WHERE
                C.[Id] = @Id;

    SELECT
                P.[Id],
                P.[Name],
                P.[CategoryId]
        FROM
                [dbo].[Product] P
        WHERE
                C.[CategoryId] = @Id;
END
```

Then, in your API/Business Logic you can serialise both result sets and combine the relationship. Something like this, [code adapted from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx).

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetCategoryAndProductByCategoryId]";

    try
    {

        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        // Run the sproc 
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Read the category from the first result set
        var category = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext
            .Translate<Category>(
                reader,
                "Category",
                MergeOption.AppendOnly)
            .Single();      

        // Move to second result set and read Products
        reader.NextResult();
        var products = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext
            .Translate<Product>(
                reader,
                "Product",
                MergeOption.AppendOnly);

        category.Products = products;
        return category;

    }
    finally
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: so can you write for me some code in c# to handle 2 select statement

Comment: how can i serialise 2 table

Comment: I am, I'd prefer to do it using Dapper

Answer (score 1):

You could get list sub-items by `XML` like that

```
SELECT  c.Id, c.Name, 
      (  SELECT p.Id, p.Name, p.CategoryId FROM Product p 
         WHERE p.CategoryId = c.Id
         FOR XML PATH ('')
      ) AS XmlProducts
from Category as c
where c.Id = @Id
```

In C#, when mapping `Category` datatable, use `XML deserialize` to get list Products object by function

```
public  T DeserialXmlToObject<T>(string xmlString) where T : new()
    {
        T result;
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            var rdr = new StringReader(xmlString);
            result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            return default(T);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Reference link: [Deserialize xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server)

[FOR XML SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server)